# Having a servlet give a 403 response when a client authentication is refused

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, ssl

I have a tomcat webapp that has SSL enabled.  I want it to return a 403 response if the client's certificate is invalid.  Is there a way to do this?  Currently, my browser will give me messages such as "Secure Connection Failed," but is there anyway to override this behavior?

Comment: which version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: Why are you trying to use HTTP status codes for SSL-specific errors?

Comment: Apparently it's easier than trying to code the servlet to handle the authorization, and it would be easier to just return 403 and have a custom 403 page.  (It wasn't my idea)

Comment: so, you want to redirect from https to http?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the work yourself. Set `clientCert=want` in your SSL configuration and then write your own code to do the certificate-chain verification. You can [do it like this](http://markmail.org/message/kzxsamuiu6bldjmv).